# Laravel com código totalmente separado

Tags: php, laravel

Programo com PHP a algum tempo já, e sempre fiz os meus projetos na mão(sem uso de framework como laravel, zend,etc..), fazendo uma estrutura muito similar ao mvc.
Porem estou querendo melhorar como programador e tendo em vista novas oportunidades de trabalho estou tentando aderir as melhores práticas do mercado, com isso em mente resolvi começar a estudar e usar o Laravel para desenvolver meus novos projetos.
Porem ao ver os vídeo aulas e mesmo a documentação vejo que é muito comum usar o PHP junto com o HTML e ignorar a existência do js. Minha pergunta é:
É errado eu querer(ou não recomendado) usar JavaScrip, PHP com o Laravel e deixar tudo separado, ou seja, na página que vai html não vai nenhum outro código além de html puro? Ou to viajando e preciso me acostumar a usar php na msm página q o html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é errado utilizar em arquivos separados.

Os tutoriais que você deve estar olhando devem estar utilizando o Blade Engine.

Na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade) do **Laravel** sobre o **Blade** ele informa:

> Blade is the simple, yet powerful templating engine provided with Laravel. Unlike other popular PHP templating engines, Blade does not restrict you from using plain PHP code in your views.

Ele permite você utilizar PHP nas views e descreve isso como um diferencial. Você pode tratar todo o código **PHP** no **Controller** e utilizar o **Blade** para manusear os dados extraídos do **Controller**.

**A utilização do Blade é opcional**.
Se você renomear um arquivo blade, por exemplo, home.blade.php para home.php, ele irá funcionar como um arquivo php comum.

Também é comum a utilização do **Vue.js**  e **ReactJS** em projetos **Laravel**, porém são coisas separadas, os tutoriais que você está vendo possivelmente deve ser focado em Laravel utilizando apenas com o PHP e Blade.

Existe uma parte na documentação especialmente para a estruturação de arquivos JS. [Documentação de estruturação do JS.](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend#writing-javascript)

Comment: Não havia me atentado ao uso do Blade, nem imaginava que ele usava npm para fazer gestão dos framework js. Obrigado pela atenção e atenção